# Nested data filtering in AWK

Tags: bash, awk

Hello I have a data file in format:

```
n tphysical outputID ###
40-column-data-here
40-column-data-here
.
.
.
40-column-data-here
n tphysical outputID ###
40-column-data-here
40-column-data-here
.
.
.
40-column-data-here
```

and so on.
What I'm having problem with is that I need to filter data based on tphysical. And to then apply condition on second column of `40 column data` for those columns which are under tphysical I'm interested in. First I thought about finding `NR` at which `awk '(NF == 4){print NR}' my/file.dat` and then piping it to another awk in which I filter `NR` based on that. But my file is very big and I think there might be some simpler way to do that.

Desired output:

```
n tphisical = some_number outputID ###
column2 column8
column2 column8
.
.
.
column2 column8
```

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Get rid of all of the `.`s in your example so you provide something concrete we can test a potential solution against.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than print NR, save the value of tphysical to a variable.  Use that value on subsequent lines.  Every time you get a line with 4 fields, you'll capture the new value of tphysical:

```
NF == 4 {tp = $2;}
$1 == 40 { v = $2; ... do something with v, referencing tp as appropriate...}
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved it! I just didn't specify it precisly - I didn't have number ```40``` at ```$1``` but 40 columns. What I did: ```awk '(NF == 4){tp = $2;}(tp == some_number){print $2, $8}' my/file.dat```